# how to change zen-cart admin password from mysql

Tags: php, zen-cart

I have a website in zen-cart. And I lost its admin password . So I opened its database table and find the row to change the admin password but it is in encrypted form . So how can I reset it with encryption and how can I test it.

I found related solution here but I don't want delete anything 
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/zen-cart/resetting-your-zencart-admin-password

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UPDATE  admin SET 'admin_pass' = '351683ea4e19efe34874b501fdbf9792:9b' WHERE 'admin_name' = YOUR-ADMIN-NAME ;
```

You should now be able to login using the following details: 
Username: Admin
Password: admin

Comment: i did it but  my password is not working and  not in encrypted form ,, login not working

Comment: Please post your db entry for this

Comment: If you hosted files & db try with forgot password and refer [this](https://www.zen-cart.com/content.php?44)  also